# Prisma - united logic for create and update operations results in Typescript errors I'm unable to overcome

Tags: typescript, express, types, prisma

I'm fairly new to Typescript and typing in general. I used to work many years with python and javascript so this is for me a whole new world. Anyways I'm trying to define `prepareData` method within my crud services. This method is called always before `create` or `update` methods are called to obtain all the data to save. Simply imagine model `Address` with field `googlePlaceId`. When request to create or update the address is made `prepareData` method makes an API call to google places to retrieve all informations about the address so it can be saved.

Let's add two more models on top of our `Address` model - `BusinessCase` and `Property`. For full context relations looks like this: `BusinessCase` FK to `Property` FK to `Address`.

Now let's get to the problem. My method looks like this:

```
async prepareData(
    data: Prisma.BusinessCaseUpdateInput | Prisma.BusinessCaseCreateInput,
    action: 'create' | 'update') {
    if(data.property && action in data.property && data.property[action].address?[action]?.googlePlaceId) {
      //API call to google places
    }
}
```

where `data.property[action]` results in:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"create" | "update"' can't be used to index type 'PropertyCreateNestedOneWithoutBusinessCasesInput | PropertyUpdateOneRequiredWithoutBusinessCasesNestedInput'.   Property 'update' does not exist on type 'PropertyCreateNestedOneWithoutBusinessCasesInput | PropertyUpdateOneRequiredWithoutBusinessCasesNestedInput'.
```

Which is funny because I check whether `action` exists in `data.property` but Typescript doesn't care. Anyways I tried to eliminate the error by telling typescript that action is keyof property:

```
data.property[action as keyof typeof data.property]!.address?[action]?.googlePlaceId
```

but `data.property[action as keyof typeof data.property]!.address` results in:

```
TS2339: Property 'address' does not exist on type '(Without<PropertyCreateWithoutBusinessCasesInput, PropertyUncheckedCreateWithoutBusinessCasesInput> & PropertyUncheckedCreateWithoutBusinessCasesInput) | (Without<...> & PropertyCreateWithoutBusinessCasesInput) | PropertyCreateOrConnectWithoutBusinessCasesInput | PropertyWhereUniqueInput'.   Property 'address' does not exist on type 'PropertyCreateOrConnectWithoutBusinessCasesInput'.
```

I wanted to suppress this error by marking `data.property[action as keyof typeof data.property] as PropertyCreateWithoutBusinessCasesInput | PropertyUpdateWithoutBusinessCasesInput` but these cannot be imported from `PrismaClient`. I also tried several other methods but always failed miserably.

**The Question:** Is there an elegant solution without too complex TS code and preferably without //@ts-ignore if possible. I also don't want to split `create` and `update` logic - I want this logic to be united so I'll have cleaner code.

Also if you are wondering why I'm hardcoding actions for `Property` and `Address` according to `BusinessCase` action - that is because of my dataflow and I'm completely ok with it. I have middleware that blocks nested `create` within `update` action.